# Cakephp 3 isAuthorized in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In a controller I am trying to give access method 'report', where user_type=3. I have tried below code. But user 3 still not able to access in report method.

My tried code:

```
 public function isAuthorized( $user )
 {
      if ( $user['user_type'] == 2 ) {
           return true;
      }elseif($user['user_type'] == 3){
           $this->Auth->allow(['report']);
      }else
      return false;
 }
```

How can I give access report method for `user_type=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `isAuthorized` is called, the `allow` list has already been checked. You could use

```
if ($user['user_type'] == 3 && $this->action == 'report')
```

Or else somewhere earlier (like `beforeFilter`), somehow (details would be very much application-specific) get the user and do your

```
if ($user['user_type'] == 3) {
    $this->Auth->allow(['report']);
}
```